# migrate data from mssql to mysql problems

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server-2008, mysql-workbench

Hi i am trying to migrate mssql data base to mysql database using mysql workbench

The problem here is when i am migrating the data the mysql workbench freezes at the last step 
which is data bulk transfer i searched the web some of the answers say's that if you are using mysql workbench on 64 bit win 7 this operation will always get freeze, is that correct ?
and should i install win 32 ? (this happen when i want to migrate every thing in mssql database).

The second problem is that, i manged to migrate few tables but no procedures or triggers are migrated and on top of that a simple query in mssql takes 0.2 sec takes on the same table on mysql 20 sec i know the problem is on the indexing but when i index the table to certain 
column the query works fine if i did select with where on that column except that the select with out where on the indexed column still very very slow.

Example :

select * from users;

this in mssql 1 sec

in mysql 20 sec

after indexing on user_type

select * from users where user_type = 2;

this in mssql 0.7 sec

in mysql 0.5 sec

but when i am back to use

select * from users;

this in mssql 0.9 sec

in mysql 18 sec

any ideas here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which other indexes exist on the table? Which is the table structure?

Comment: so there is no other indexes on the table and the table structure is
user_id, name , email(P_K) , user_type, last_login, country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after many trays i found the solution which is :

when the data is migrated from mssql to mysql, mysql assume that you want to use InnoDB as default engine and when you do the migrate you will lose the indexes, routines and  procedures, so for that when you run the data on InnoDB it will be very slow until you recreate new indexes, routines and procedures.

but when you specify that you want to use MyISAM as default engine the select query will be incredibly fast without doing the above and if the above were made it will make the query faster.

but this work for reading rows, because MyISAM  is really great for reading rows but for write InnoDB  will be the boss and of course if the read/write are needed InnoDB also will be the boss but after recreating the above.

so for my case i just added ENGINE=MyISAM after each table create statement and when i do any query even if i was fetching 200k rows, it took me almost 2 sec to get the result.

Comment: I was having similar problem. Let me try and update you.